# Wordpress Slider with rotation animation

Tags: wordpress, slider

Does anyone know what this slider?

https://www.crescentheights.com

If you look at the header slider it's kinda rotating with highlights.

Your help is really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The slider at your example url is powered by FlatFolio from UnCommons. It's available to buy through CodeCanyon.

https://codecanyon.net/item/flatfolio-flat-cool-wp-portfolio/9294349

Comment: can you send me the link?

Comment: @rolex I added the Link to the post

Comment: i don't see a random changes in fade in.